# Car jerking when engine warms up

Tags: audi, dtc, p0340, p0304

Hey so my car drives great when the engine is cold, but once it warms up to 90 degrees it starts jerking a lot when pressing accelerator. I scanned the car and got codes: p0340(camshaft position sensor "A" circuit), p1504(something about the intake leak I think it might be my pcv valve hose) also p0304(4 cylinder misfire but i changed spark plugs and coils). Okay so maybe you what would be the problem for jerking when warmed up and where should i start fixing?